# How to completely remove Calibre under Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, uninstall, calibre

I installed *calibre* manually under Debian Linux Squeeze. Compare to its functionality, the mime-type problem of *calibre* drives me crazy! It associates almost everything with itself! Almost everything failed if I try to open some file using `xdg-open` in a terminal. What a idiot design!

Comment: Please note that the "code" formatting should be used only to wrap actual code or console commands; to just give emphasis you could use italics or bold text.

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
sudo calibre-uninstall
```

It works for me.

Comment: This works for me also

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo python /usr/bin/calibre-uninstall
sudo rm -rf /opt/calibre
```

Comment: It seems the second command is unnecessary, /opt/calibre is already removed by the first command.

Comment: Simply running `sudo calibre-uninstall` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
apt-get --purge remove <package>
```

package being the calibre package.

Comment: I installed calibre `manually`, that is to say, `by hand`, not through `apt`.

Comment: Due to the fact Calibre updates so often, Calibre recommends a script they publish to install.  They recommend against apt and package installers.